# Website’s security certificate issue with IE on Windows10

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, ssl-certificate, trusted-root-certificates

On one of my PC, whenever I open a website with HTTPS, it shows the error message "There is a problem with this website’s security certificate."

IE 11 on 64Bit Windows 10 Enterprise.

I have already tried:

1. Verified the date time is correct.
2. Unchecked the "Check Publisher's certificate revocation", "Check
   server certificate revocation" and "Warn about certificate address
   mismatch" in Internet Options > Advanced > Security
3. Installed certificate after clicking on "Continue to this website"

Comment: So you have installed the certificate in the User's Certificate Store I assume?  You did this as an Administrator and placed it into the correct bucket of certificates?  Provide more details on the background of this certificate.  Does this happen on any website, including say, any Google/Microsoft websites.  If thats the case then you have a MITM configuration, and in that case, you need to give us more details.

Comment: It happens to all website with HTTPS, i have checked it with google, gmail, my website, stackoverflow etc... Same website works perfectly on other devices in same network.